# How to fix discord js bot not running repl.it (no errors)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I made a bot in repl.it and it seemed to work fine, but when I ran it today it stopped working. The express server starts, but the bot seems to be offline because the **client.on(ready)** event is not working. Can you please suggest me what's wrong?

Comment: Can you shos some of the relevant code, specifically how you login your bot and your ready event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be one possible error ( your bot got ratelimited ) to view if that issue happened add this to your code:

```js
client.on("debug", ( e ) => console.log(e));
```

If it returns

```
HIT: 429 // ROUTE ON GATEWAY
```

it most probably is a ratelimit, this is one of the common reasons of the `client.once("ready")` event not triggering since discord.js provides internal ratelimits, to remove it please wait around 24 hours or make a new repl ( by forking your current repl )